# С удаленного клиента достучаться до сервера в локальной сети

Tags: сеть, клиент-сервер, nat, маршрутизатор

Есть сервер, который подключен к интернету через маршрутизатор. Удаленный клиент знает лишь внешний ip адрес маршрутизатора. Какая еще нужна информация о сервере, и как ее использовать на стороне клиента, чтобы без изменений в настройках маршрутизатора и сервера пакеты от клиента шли именно к серверу?

Comment: Никак, обычно делается port forwarding или правила на роутере, который стоит между внутренней сетью и внешним миром.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov А как веб сервер отправляет ответ устройству в локальной сети?

Comment: @EduardGushchin веб-сервер отправляет ответ тому, кто послал запрос. А дальше маршрутизатор разбирается. Но это именно что настройка маршрутизатора такая, просто она по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типичная схема работы Port-based NAT в конфигурации по умолчанию выглядит так:

1. Когда пакет проходит из внутренней сети наружу - у него подменяется адрес и порт отправителя, при этом в некоторую таблицу записывается соответствие.
2. Когда пакет приходит снаружи - выполняется поиск в таблице по номеру порта получателя. Если запись найдена - то адрес и порт получателя меняются на запомненные в таблице. Если не найдена - пакет отбрасывается.

---

Исходя из написанного выше должно быть ясно, что NAT пропускает соединения только в одну сторону. Если клиент находится внутри, а сервер снаружи - пакеты смогут ходить в обоих направлениях. Если сервер внутри - то клиенты снаружи никак к нему не достучатся.

Обычно, когда возникает необходимость разместить сервер внутри NAT - на маршрутизаторе настраивают fort forwarding, неформально - пробрасывают порт. Но это требует именно что дополнительных настроек маршрутизатора.

Если по условию задачи маршрутизатор настраивать нельзя - то решения в общем случае **нет**. А если еще и сервер тоже нельзя трогать - то решения нет **совсем**. *Запомните: когда ничего не работает - это называется "Безопасность"!*

---

PS обходные пути для случая, когда у вас нет доступа к маршрутизатору - но есть к серверу

1. Развернуть направление соединения. Пусть сервер выступает в роли клиента (начинает установку соединения) - а клиент в роли сервера (слушает порт). Скорее всего, им понадобится третий участник - "сигнальный" сервер где-нибудь в облаке, который передаст реальному серверу что с ним хочет соединиться клиент.
2. Туннель до доверенного сервера в облаке. Проще всего использовать ssh, там есть несколько режимов, посвященных пробросу порта через шифрованное соединение. Вам подойдет Remote port forwarding (ключ -R)
3. VPN
4. Можно попробовать открыть порт по UPnP, который на некоторых маршрутизаторах включен по умолчанию. Заходите в сетевое окружение, находите там маршрутизатор, в его свойствах ищите список открытых портов. Если не нашли - не судьба.
5. Перейти на протокол UDP, где есть решения вроде STUN (это баг NAT, ставший важной фичей для P2P-сетей; работает не для всех реализаций NAT)

Comment: Спасибо. Буду копать в сторону STUN.

Comment: @EduardGushchin начните лучше с пункта 1. Потому что STUN тоже требует третьего сервера точно так же, как все остальные пункты кроме 4.

Comment: А если организовать полноценную p2p сеть?

Comment: @EduardGushchin все равно нужны какие-то точки входа в сеть

Comment: Не понимаю. p2p же по идее полностью децентрализованная сеть, а третьего сервера требует лишь при организации гибридной сети для быстрого поиска участников. Или нет? Я не очень в сетевом программировании, и устройство децентрализованных сетей для меня - черная магия. Буду очень признателен, если посоветуете годную литературу.